# Get System time, localstorage, compare dates and performe an action

Tags: javascript, date, comparison, storage

I need to get the system time once, then store it on localStorage, then compare this stored value with a further system date and then perform an action if the future date is equal or greater than the one which is stored. I have tried but I am stucked in making the function which gets the system time the first time to run only once so I can get a future date to compare.
This is my code

```
console.log(formatTime());

function formatTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  return (strTime = date.getDay() + "/" + date.getMonth() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + ampm);
}

document.getElementById("currentdt").innerHTML = strTime;

var strTime1 = formatTime();
var timeString = JSON.stringify(strTime1);
localStorage.setItem("strTime1", timeString);
var timeStringFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("strTime1");
var timeFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(timeStringFromLocalStorage);

document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = strTime1;
console.log(timeStringFromLocalStorage);

function compare(dateTimeA, dateTimeB) {
  var momentA = moment(dateTimeA, "strTime1");
  var momentB = moment(dateTimeB, "strTime");
  if (momentA > momentB) return 1;
  else if (momentA < momentB) return -1;
  else return 0;
}

alert(compare("strTime1", "strTime"));
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I am using moment.js for date comparison.

Comment: Currently you're trying to compare strings as dates, how come? Won't the stored date always be older than the current date?

Comment: yes, it will be older. What I need is to say, you run the page today, so that date is stored. Every time you run the page the script should check the stored date and when a lapse of, let's say, 15 days have passed then the script should redirect you to another page (this last part isn't included in the code I have posted). The problem is that I need a code fix so that the date is stored just once, the first time ran. I am stack there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below will check if there has been a value set in localStorage. If there is no value set, it will set its first and stop the function.

If there is a value, then it will be turned into a `moment` instance and compared with the current date. If a difference in days is equal or larger to than specified it will redirect the page.

```js
function redirectWhenOlderThan(days, url) {
  const storedValue = localStorage.getItem('first-visit');
  const now = moment();
  
  /**
   * If nothing is stored yet, then storedValue will be null.
   * Here you will set the first localStorage item for the first time.
   * Instead of a full date, store the timestamp.
   * Then stop the function.
   */
  if (storedValue === null) {
    localStorage.setItem('first-visit', now.valueOf().toString());
    return;
  }

  /**
   * If there is a stored value then it will be a timestamp as a string.
   * First parse it into a number before putting it into moment.
   * Then check the difference in days between the dates.
   */
  const then = moment(Number(storedValue));
  const difference = now.diff(then, 'days');

  /**
   * If the difference is higher or equal to the given days, redirect.
   */
  if (difference >= days) {
    location.href = url;
  }
}
```

Call the function with amount of days that should have passed since the first visit and the URL to redirect to.

```
redirectWhenOlderThan(15, 'https://example.com');
```

I hope this is what you meant.

**Sidenote:** dive into `moment.js` if you have the time. It has a lot of features that could spare you some time, like your `formatTime()` function, it can be written in a single line with moment.

```
moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss A');
```

Comment: By just analyzing your simple and neat solution I can say it was exactly what I meant. But I will wait until tomorrow to check if it really do the trick as I set just 1 day of difference to test it. I set 0 days and it redirected, so I think it will work.

Comment: Well, as I said, a day has elapsed and it works very fine. Now I'm going to set a delay because the redirection occurs instantly and I would like to let the user still see the index.page. But it really works.

Comment: Sorry Emiel Zuurbier but in my hurry I accepted your answer but didn't voted it up. I did just now. Hope it will be enough to pay for my bad memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

Now the final code goes like this

```
    function formatTime() {
    var date = new Date();
    return strTime = date.getDay() + '/' + date.getMonth()+'/'+date.getFullYear();

    }
    document.getElementById("currentdt").innerHTML = strTime;


    function redirectWhenOlderThan(days, url) {
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem('first-visit');
    const now = moment();

    if (storedValue === null) {
    localStorage.setItem('first-visit', now.valueOf().toString());
    return;
    }

    const then = moment(Number(storedValue));
    const difference = now.diff(then, 'days');


    if (difference >= days) {
    location.href = url;
    }
    else {
    window.location.href= 'app/phr.html';
    }
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
    redirectWhenOlderThan(1, 'app/licences.html');
    }, 3000);
```